# How to switch back from orphan branch to master branch?

Tags: git

Initial situation:

I have developed a test station. During development, I used Git as version management. When handing over the test station to a partner, I used `git checkout --orphan <partner>` and `git rm -rf .` to create a separate `partner` branch without the development history and then used `git commit` to add only these elements to this branch the partner needs.

This means that my repository is currently in the orphan `partner` branch, and the files that I don't want to share with the partner are labelled as `unstaged files`.

Question:

Now I want to continue the developement.
However, if I now want to return to my `master` branch with `git checkout master`, this action is denied with the message `The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout`. I have not changed anything in the files. In addition, the files are also contained in the `master` branch so an overwriting wouldn't cause any problems. How do I get back to my master branch? How to get `HEAD` pointing again to the last commit of `master`? Is `git checkout -f master` a proper way?

I use Sourcetree as the GUI for git.

An abstact example:

branch `master` contains files: `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`

branch `partner` contains files: `A`, `C`; files `B` & `D` marked as unstaged

`git checkout master` fails with message `The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout: B, D`

[Edit]: Added information based on comment.

Comment: `git checkout --orphan <branch>` should keep all files staged, which leaves no untracked files, unless you reset them from the index. In your case, `git checkout -f master` is okay. You could also move/remove them or stash them (`git stash -u`) first. Another option is to use `git worktree add master` to create a linked worktree for `master` so that the 2 branches are checked out at 2 separate folders.

Comment: @ElpieKay: You are right, after `git checkout --orphan <partner>` I did `git rm -rf .` to remove all files from the index. Then I added a subset of the files to the new branch.

Comment: Correction, `git worktree add master` should be `git worktree add /path/to/foo master`.

Comment: The "orphan" part here is irrelevant. The same error message appears if you are switching branches and have untracked files that might be overwritten.

Comment: As it says, you have some files which would be overwritten by the checkout. You might be able to see them with `git status`.
To remove everything run `git clean -fxd`, then you should be able to checkout master again.